# What could be the difference between the following two output code snippets?

Tags: python, list

For the first `Output = [3, 8, 7, 9]` I had given manual input and for the second `Output = ['3', '8', '7', '9']` I had asked for an input list. So, now I am wondering both being the lists what could be the diff?

Comment: One list contains int elements. The other contains string elements. I assume this is because you created a for loop asking for string inputs. Yes you entered integers but python changed them to string. ```(input("Enter a number"))``` I assume

Comment: Fair enough, understood.. thanks! :)

Comment: Might be useful: [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20449427/2745495)

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask] from the [tour]. "Teach me this basic language feature" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a _specific_ question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score -1):

One list contains integer (`int`) values, while the other contains string (`str`) values. An integer value can be used in mathematical equations and mathematical comparisons (for instance, `if x > 0`), while string values are usually used to display words or text, and cannot be used in equations. For instance, if you had

```
string_var = "1"
int_var = 1

print(int_var * 2)
print(string_var * 2)
```

The string variable (in quotes) cannot be multiplied (it instead returns `11`, which obviously isn't correct. The integer variable is multiplied successfully. Strings are better used when saving words or non-number values into a variable. You can research more on strings and integers online.

Answer (score -1):

as **BuddyBobIII** said, all of the first list elements are `int`s which refers to `Integer`s as [whole numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer), but the second one are `string`s which refers to text elements and cannot use in mathematical operations.

if you want to change the second to integers, you can use `map` function to change all elements of an iterable variable to integers:

```
a = ['1','2', '3' , '4']

print(list(map(int, a)))
```

**Output**:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```